# M.2 drives: difference in performance when plugged into different PCI lanes

Tags: ssd, pci-express, m.2

A M.2 SSD can be plugged either into the PCI lanes that go straight to the CPU (if you're using a CPU that supports more than 16 lanes), or into the PCI lanes that go to the chipset.

Is there any performance difference when plugged into one or the other? Let's assume that:

- We are using, as said above, a CPU that supports more than 16 lanes, and the first 16 are taken by the graphics card.
- The computer will have another 3 SATA drives, as well as the assorted USB 3 ports, sound chipset, LAN, etc.

Are there any benchmarks that measure this difference?

Comment: Any benchmark would do - if it was measurable. It depends on your board and the layout of the lanes as well as the specific CPU.

Comment: @Seth: well, the problem is that I don't have a board or a CPU yet ;-). I'm researching to build a new PC, and I'm wondering whether to buy a regular Intel one (which has only 16 direct-to-the-CPU lanes) or some of the higher-end ones that have more. Obviously, the graphics card would take 16 lanes, so the decision would depend on whether the M.2 drive needs more or it can be plugged into the chipset lanes without damaging performance too much.

Answer (score 1):

The results are going to depend on several critical factors

1. Can your M.2 drive actually come close to maxing out PCIe x4
2. What versions of PCI express do your CPU and chipset support? Sometimes chipset lanes are a generation behind CPU lanes.
3. What else is the system doing? the chipset to CPU interface is typically the equivalent of an x4 connection. So if there is a bunch of other traffic running over said interface then it could become a bottleneck

Having said that under desktop use cases with a modern CPU and chip-set (so the chipset lanes support PCIe 3.0) I doubt you will notice any difference.